# What's the difference between apache's RequestConfig and IOReactorConfig?

Tags: rest, apache-httpasyncclient

I was looking for a way to set custom timeouts in HttpAsyncClients, and googling gave me two ways - using RequestConfig or IOReactorConfig. Both seem similar and I could not find much explanation about what each of these are.